# redis key set to expire not actually removed

Tags: redis, ttl

Is the following behavior expected in Redis, version:2.8.19:

```
127.0.0.1:6380> set fooxyz 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6380> ttl fooxyz
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6380> expire fooxyz 3
(integer) 1
(1.98s)
127.0.0.1:6380> ttl fooxyz
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6380> ttl fooxyz
(integer) 0
(0.96s)
127.0.0.1:6380> ttl fooxyz
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6380> ttl fooxyz
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6380> get fooxyz
"1"
```

As you can see, I set an expire on the key  `fooxyz`, it reaches 0, but then it is never actually removed. I continue to be able to retrieve the value of fooxyz after the expire time.

Is that to be expected? Will it eventually be removed/garbage collected?

According to the [redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/expire),

> A key is actively expired simply when some client tries to access it,
>   and the key is found to be timed out.

And yet here I have an example of actively attempting to retrieve the key, and it not being expired.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844944/number-of-expiring-keys-listed-by-info-command-on-redis-slave-not-consistent-wit and this post https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2861 -- Basically key expiry behaves differently on slaves

Answer (score 0):

esilver, I can't reproduce your problem in v3.2.2, the lazy expire works fine for me:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set fooxyz 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl fooxyz
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6379> expire fooxyz 3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl fooxyz
(integer) -2
127.0.0.1:6379> get fooxyz
(nil)
```

Comment: Do you agree that repeatedly getting a ttl of 0 for a key is weird? Also - this is on a redis process that is slaving a master but is not readonly, meaning I can also write to the slave. Do you think that could be related?

Comment: Yes, it's weird. And I still can't repro it in a writable slave.

Answer (score 0):

@esilver
Yes, it's weird. And I still can't repro it on a writable slave :(

```
127.0.0.1:6000> info replication
# Replication
role:slave       <=======
master_host:127.0.0.1
master_port:6001
master_link_status:up
master_last_io_seconds_ago:1
master_sync_in_progress:0
slave_repl_offset:24786
slave_priority:100
slave_read_only:0     <=======
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0
127.0.0.1:6000> set fooxyz 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6000> ttl fooxyz
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6000> expire fooxyz 3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6000> ttl fooxyz
(integer) -2
127.0.0.1:6000> get fooxyz
(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it is happening on a slave. Could it be the case that you have such a key on master, `SET` it on a slave, `EXPIRE` it on a slave, it gets expired and restored from master?

**EDIT** I tested it on 4.0.9 with one master and one writable slave and it was not the case. The key on a slave correctly expired and was deleted automatically even without `GET` access. You may still try to test this case on your version.

Comment: I believe key expiry behaves differently on slaves -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844944/number-of-expiring-keys-listed-by-info-command-on-redis-slave-not-consistent-wit and https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2861