# Number of expiring keys listed by info command on redis slave not consistent with what I see

Tags: redis

When I run the `info` command in `redis-cli` against a redis 3.2.4 server, it shows me this for expires:

`expires=223518`

However, when I then run a `keys *` command and ask for the `ttl` for each key, and only print out keys with a ttl > 0, I only see a couple hundred.

I thought that the `expires` is a count of the number of expiring keys but I am not even within an order of magnitude of this number.

Can someone clarify exactly what `expires` is meant to convey? Does this include both to-be-expired and previously expired but not yet evicted keys?

---

Update:

Here is how I counted the number of keys expiring:

```
  task count_tmp_keys: :environment do
    redis = Redis.new(timeout: 100)
    keys = redis.keys '*'
    ct_expiring = 0

    keys.each do |k|
      ttl = redis.ttl(k)
      if ttl > 0
        ct_expiring += 1
        puts "Expiring: #{k}; ttl is #{ttl}; total: #{ct_expiring}"
        STDOUT.flush
      end
    end

    puts "Total expiring: #{ct_expiring}"
    puts "Done at #{Time.now}"
  end
```

When I ran this script it shows I have a total expiring of 78

When I run info, it says `db0:keys=10237963,expires=224098,avg_ttl=0`

Because 224098 is so much larger than 78, I am very confused. Is there perhaps a better way for me to obtain a list of all 225k expiring keys?

Also, how is it that my average ttl is 0? Wouldn't you expect it to be nonzero?

---

**UPDATE**

I have new information and a simple, 100% repro of this situation locally!

To repro: setup two redis processes locally on your laptop. Make one a slave of the other. On the slave process, set the following:

```
config set slave-serve-stale-data yes
config set slave-read-only no
```

Now, connect to the slave (not the master) and run:

```
set foo 1
expire foo 10
```

After 10 seconds, you will no longer be able to access foo, but `info` command will still show that you have 1 key expiring with an average ttl of 0.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expires` contains existing keys with TTL which will expire, not including already expired keys.
Example ( with omission of extra information from `info` command for brevity ):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> flushall
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX mykey1 1000 "1"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX mykey2 1000 "2"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX mykey3 1000 "3"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> info
# Keyspace
db0:keys=3,expires=3,avg_ttl=992766
127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX mykey4 1 "4"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX mykey5 1 "5"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> info
# Keyspace
db0:keys=3,expires=3,avg_ttl=969898
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "mykey2"
2) "mykey3"
3) "mykey1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Given that in your situation you are asking about key expiry on slaves, per https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2861:

> keys on a slave are not actively expired, and thus the avg_ttl is
>   never calculated

And per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/NFTpdmpOPnc:

> avg_ttl is never initialized on a slave and thus it can be what ever 
>   arbitrary value resides in memory at that place.

Thus, it is to be expected that the `info` command behaves differently on slaves.

Comment: Hi @DruvPathak -- I have just shared my script. Thanks!

Comment: @esilver Can you please confirm that you are connecting to same db in shell as well as script ?

Comment: @DruvPathak Yes I am connecting to the same DB.

Comment: Also - how can the average ttl be zero across *so many* keys as you can see from my snippet above? Doesn't that seem suspicious?

Comment: @esilver Are you connecting to master or slave ? I doubt your info is coming from slave.

Comment: I am connecting to a slave instance that is write-enabled. The slave rapidly creates and then deletes temporary keys. The slave is performing a large number of set intersection operations to power a real-time search. There are few (<500) expiring/expirable keys coming from the master.

Comment: @esilver The `info` command has correct output for master as per documentation, your command on master would give you the desired result.

Comment: OK - then the mystery continues...I have hundreds of thousands of keys that reportedly expire in 0 seconds, but I cannot locate them....

Comment: @esilver Can you please update the question with results of `info` on both master and slave ? Especially the `keys=xxxxxxxxx,expires=xxxxxx,avg_ttl=xxxx` section

Comment: I have a repro of this situation now! You should be able to see this for yourself too -- do you have any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Because in slave key expiry works differently, see : https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2861 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/NFTpdmpOPnc . These behaviours might have changed in most recent versions of redis, but the master-slave mechanism difference would stay by design. I have updated the answer too to reflect this.

Comment: thanks for helping me solve this mystery! I have accepted your answer and updated it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The expires just returns the size of keys that will expire not the time.

The [source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/c01abcdebf4fa2b1cd3d3a89049651d528ed5656/src/server.c#L3296-L3304) of 3.2.4

```
long long keys, vkeys;

keys = dictSize(server.db[j].dict);
vkeys = dictSize(server.db[j].expires);
if (keys || vkeys) {
    info = sdscatprintf(info,
        "db%d:keys=%lld,expires=%lld,avg_ttl=%lld\r\n",
        j, keys, vkeys, server.db[j].avg_ttl);
}
```

It just calculate the size of `server.db[j].expires`. (note j is the database index).